# Is there any method to add multiple files to data_files in a setup file automatically created by py2app?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, py2app

I'm a newbie in python and programming in general. Recently I've made a small card game using pygame library and now I want to have a standalone app executable on Mac. I'm using py2app to do so. Unfortunately, I have some issues with adding files into data_files when editing a setup file, created automatically by py2app. I have about 60 .png files, located in two folders. Is there any way to load them into the setup file automatically? Or I have to do it manually? Also, I can't figure out where in the setup file I can add the location directory of these files.

Here is the code:

```
    from setuptools import setup

    APP = ['Blackjack.py']
    DATA_FILES = []
    OPTIONS = {}

    setup(
        app=APP,
        data_files=DATA_FILES,
        options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I haven't tested it yet, but it should work. In your data files just add this instead of the files: `[*f1_files, *f2_files]`

```
import os

FOLDER_1 = "Path/To/Your/First/Folder"
FOLDER_2 = "Path/To/Your/Second/Folder"

f1_files = [os.path.join(FOLDER_1, file) for file in os.listdir(FOLDER_1)]
f2_files = [os.path.join(FOLDER_2, file) for file in os.listdir(FOLDER_2)]
```